# C++ How to properly copy the value of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

So I'm having a bit of an issue, and need help with this beginner question.

I've changed my example so that it makes sense. I should not have posted one while sleep deprived.

I'm trying to copy a pointer (lets call it p1) in order to create a second pointer (lets call it p2).

When p1 changes the object it is pointing at, I don't want p2 to change along with it, which is what appears to be happening in my program.

Essentially, here is the issue I'm having....

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    std::cout << "Pointer Test\n\n";

    int num1, num2;
    int * p1, * p2;

    num1 = 5;
    num2 = 10;

    p1 = &num1;
    p2 = p1;

    std::cout << "P1 is pointing at value " << *p1 << " (should be 5)\n";
    std::cout << "P2 is pointing at value " << *p2 << " (should be 5)\n\n";

    *p1 = num2;     //Even though the value of P1 is changing, I don't want the value of P2 to change. I want it to stay on num1

    std::cout << "P1 is pointing at value " << *p1 << " (should be 10)\n";
    std::cout << "P2 is pointing at value " << *p2 << " (I want this to be 5, not 10)\n";

    return 0;
}

 /* 
 Assignments I've tried to make this work...

 p2 = p1;      //didn't work - *p2 changes when *p1 does, which I am trying to avoid
 *p2 = *p1;    //didn't work - caused segfault
 *p2 = p1;     //didn't work - can't convert int to *int, so won't compile
 p2 = &(*p1);  //didn't work - gave same result as p2 = p1
*/
```

Any enlightenment on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I read the article and created a new example based on what it said. Sorry to have wasted everyone's time with the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what is going on. The statement `*p1 = num2;` is not changing the value of `p1`, it is changing the value of whatever `p1` *points* to. Since both `p1` and `p2` point to the same variable when you change its value through one pointer you will see the same value when you dereference either pointer. What you want to do is have `p1` point to `num2`, not take the value of `num2` and store it in whatever `p1` points to.

Change

```
*p1 = num2;
```

to

```
p1 = &num2;
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand that distinction. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following code:

```
int a = 5, b = 10, *foo, *bar;

    foo = &a; // foo now points at the address of A
    bar = foo; // bar now points at the address at which foo is pointing

    foo = &b; // foo now points at the address of B

    cout << *foo; // prints 10
    cout << *bar; // prints 5
```

Thats the behaviour you want to achieve if Im not mistaken.

Your code is nonsensical however. IF I'm not wrong, your mistake is that you create a second pointer which points at the address of the first pointer instead of pointing at the address from the first pointer.

Comment: Yes! You are exactly correct - I want the 2nd pointer to point to the address that the first pointer is pointing to. I'm not sure what the syntax is to do that, because when I try *p1 = *p2; it gives me an error. I have posted a new example since the first one made so sense. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code makes no sense. If testObj isn´t a typedef to a pointer,
the `*` in the first p1 assignment is wrong (it should be `&`), and the second p1 assignment is wrong too, because you can´t assign a temporary object to a pointer, (only addresses to variables or from new).
And always remember to assign an address to a pointer p before using `*p`

If you want to copy pointers, the copy will point to the same thing as the original one and `p2 = p1;` is correct. If you want to copy objects, the pointer thing has nothing to do with it, and how the object is copied should be defined in a copy constructor and operator=.
Depending on the class, memcpy can work or not, don´t rely on it for such cases.

Comment: Very sorry for the nonsensical code. I vow to never again post a question while sleep deprived. I've posted a new example that shows more clearly what it is I am looking to accomplish. 

I am not trying to copy an object. I simply want p2 to point to the same object as p1. However what I am finding is that when I reassign p1, the value of p2 changes, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Nonsensical code aside

> When p1 changes the object it is pointing at, I don't want p2 to change along with it

If `p1` and `p2` point to the same object, changing the object `p1` points to will change the (same) object `p2` points to, period. You'll have to use a different mechanism than raw pointers to avoid that behaviour. Like making copies of the object pointed to instead of copying the pointer.

Also

> Do I have to use memcpy? Or is there another way?

Since this is C++, I'd avoid `memcpy`.

Defining a [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) or [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) is a better way of copying objects.

Comment: _"If p1 and p2 point to the same object, changing p1 will change p2, period."_ - The only way that statement is even remotely correct is if `p2` is a reference to `p1`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious bad wording on my side, I meant *changing the object pointed by p1/p2*, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

There is no type like `obj *`. The "*" binds tighter to "p1". So you need to change the decl from

```
obj * p1, p2;
```

To

```
obj *p1, *p2;
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I should not have posted this question with such a crummy example. I've replaced it with a real, working one. Thank you.